# Why can't I add artwork to my music in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music

I have a few songs that don't have artwork, and would like to manually add the cover art. I'm trying to use iTunes (Get Info > Artwork > Add Artwork). However, the 'Add Artwork' button is grayed out and cannot be clicked. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry! I meant to say 'add artwork'.

Comment: You can usually just drag an image to that area.

Comment: Where did the song come from, how did it get into iTunes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason the **Add Artwork** button can be grayed out when selecting a song in **iTunes** and then **Get Info**, is the *file* does not have *write permissions* set.

Select the song in **iTunes** and then *right-click* it, then select **Show in Finder**.

In **Finder** select the *file* and then *right-click* it, then select **Get Info**.

Under the **Sharing & Permissions:** does it show **Read only** for you?  If yes change the *permissions* so you have **Read & Write** *permissions*.

The image below shows **Add Artwork** grayed out when the *file permissions* are set to **Read only**.

[image: Read only Permissions]

The image below shows **Add Artwork** active when the *file permissions* are set to **Read & Write**.

[image: Read & Write Permissions]

If it shows **Read only** for you, then click the **Lock** icon on the **Get Info** *sheet* and enter your password and then click the arrow next to the permission for *Your Name (Me)* and select **Read & Write**, then click the **Lock** icon.

---

Another reason can be the file type is not one that supports manually embedding artwork, such as a .wav file. That said, artwork should be able to be added through the iTunes Store which will save it separately if it's not a file type that supports embedded art work.

Comment: Thank you! but that doesn't work for me, I have read & write in the finder but the add artwork button is still grey.

Comment: OK I got it, it;s because it's a wave file, works on .aif

Comment: Another possible reason is the file format is .wav

Comment: @WGroleau, That was already mentioned in the comment by Nicolas Lemasson directly above your comment!

Comment: I know.  Either the browser or SE chose not to show me that comment until after!